# Entity Framework SQL Error 19: 'Foreign KEY constraint failed'

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Github Repo: https://github.com/blueboy90780/Coffee-POS-System/tree/master

I have small console application using .NET 6 and EF Core 6.0 with an SQLite database. When running my code I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Coffee_Shop_POS_System___EF_Core_6._0.MainProgram.Main() in /home/davidnguyen/Documents/Coffee Shop POS System/Coffee Shop POS System - EF Core 6.0/MainProgram.cs:line 61

Process finished with exit code 134.
```

The error message points out it happened on Line 61 inside the `MainProgram.cs` file. Which is this code

```cs
database.SaveChanges();
```

I've tried deleting the database and migrations folder, creating new ones in it's place and repopulating the database from a backup copy without working.

Why is my source code throwing this particular error?

Comment: You have to post the relevant code here instead of providing the whole repo link

Answer (score 1):

The error says something about the foreign key, so I would look after, you you insert or delete in the right way.

Example:
If you are trying to delete and item, you have to delete it in the table, where the foreignkey are placed, before it can be deleted in the table, where it occured with the primary key.

What code are you trying to run in your switchcase, in the mainprogram.cs file